# Nested arrays in JSON object posted to ASP.NET MVC Action not binding to children

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Given the following (in actual practice, is gleaned from https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable jQuery Sortable plugin's serialize function followed by JSON.stringify(...)):

```
 var testData = '[ { "id": 123, "name": "Reason Number 1" }, { "id": 124, "name": "Reason Number 3" }, { "id": 125, "name": "Reason Number 3", "children": [ { "id": 155, "name": "Child 1" } ] } ]';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: testData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
 ....
```

When fired off to the following Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public CustomJsonResult Sort(IList<NestedSortableItem> items)
 {
     //...
 }
```

Where the `NestedSortableItem` is the following:

```
public class NestedSortableItem
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    IList<NestedSortableItem> children { get; set; } 
}
```

Only the containing array is mapped while all `children` are null.. How do I map a recursively nested object of arrays so that more than just the first array is properly mapped? Does it need a custom model binder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably kick yourself :) Your property `children` is `private`. It needs to be `public`.

```
public IList<NestedSortableItem> children { get; set; }
```

Comment: You sir win all the internets! Sob. I'm still laughing.